# Servlet call failing. Using spring rest

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, pom.xml

I am trying to call a servlet by using requestMapping annotation.I have a index.html page which runs on server. But when I try to call a servlet by typing
http://localhost:8080/spring-rest/api/users it doesnt work. I have 5  classes in my project. Here's is the code.

User.java

```
    package io.egen.entity;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class User {


    public User(String id, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String compnay) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.compnay = compnay;
    }
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String compnay;
}
```

UserController.java

```
package io.egen.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import io.egen.entity.User;
import io.egen.services.UserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService services;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return services.findAll();
    }

}
```

UserService.java

```
    package io.egen.services;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import io.egen.entity.User;

@Service
public class UserService {

    public List<User> findAll() {
        System.out.println("Inside UserService");
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
        users.add(new User(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "Praveen1", "Salitra", "psalitra1@egen.io", "Egen Solutions"));
        users.add(new User(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "Praveen2", "Salitra", "psalitra2@egen.io", "Egen Solutions"));
        users.add(new User(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "Praveen3", "Salitra", "psalitra3@egen.io", "Egen Solutions"));
        return users;
    }
}
```

AppInitializer.java

```
package io.egen;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class AppInitializer  extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class [] {AppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        System.out.println("HEy");
        return new String [] {"/api/*"};
    }


}
```

AppConfig.java

```
    package io.egen;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig {

}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.egen</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-rest</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <name>spring-rest Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.8</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.38</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-b01</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>

</project>
```

[Here is my package structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrvFh.png)

I am trying to call the findAll method in UserController.java which in turn calls the findAll method in USerService.java. But I think the getservletMappings method in AppInitializer.java is not working.

Help me out.

Thanks !

Comment: What does "it doesn't work mean"?

Comment: When I try to call the servlet from browser usin the url   http://localhost:8080/spring-rest/api/users, it says 404 not found. but the Userservice class has some raw data which returns this data in JSON format to the browser. It has to show the data on the browser

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple issues in your code:

1. You should probably change your `ComponentScan` annotation like so to explicitly mention packages:

   `@ComponentScan({"io.egen.controller", "..."})`
2. Your controller is mapped to `/users` but your `AppInitializer` is only configuring mappings for `/api/*` so your controller will not be handled by Spring's `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: I changed the @ComponentScan which explicityl mentions the packages. So what changes is to be done in AppInitializer to get this work.

Comment: @vishwanathjayanth You can change it to `/*` instead of `/api/*` to test.

Comment: In that case you'll have to look in the server logs and possibly configure spring to output debug level logs

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. May I know how to do that.

Comment: Is there anyone who knows what is the mistake ?